# Copy text into blank lines with sed

Tags: bash, text, sed, text-processing

It's possible to copy a specific text into each blank line with `sed`?

Input1:

```
blabla
```

Input2:

```
1
2
3
4

5
6
7
8

etc...
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
blabla
5
6
7
8
blabla
etc...
```

Maybe there is a universal method? (regardless of which lines are empty)

Input 2:

```
1

2
3
4

5
6

etc...
```

Output:

```
1
blabla
2
3
4
blabla
5
6
blabla
etc...
```

Comment: You could use `sed` for anything you can match a pattern for.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat input.txt | sed 's/^\s*$/NEWTEXT/g'`

Comment: where newtext can be blablabla or whatever string you want.

Comment: Why do you use `cat`?